# willFocus event in react navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I need to fetch data before *focus* event. I saw that there was an *willFocus* event in [react navigation 4](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-events/) but it seems that the event was removed in [react navigation 5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/). 
*componentDidMount* cannot do the trick because I want to fetch data as soon as possible even before the screen comes into focus **each time the user navigate to my screen**.

Answer (score 2):

You CANNOT fetch data before componentDidMount. That's literally the first thing happens when a new screen is rendered.

Regarding fetching data each time when the screen is focused, you need to use `focus` event as mentioned in the migration guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#navigation-events

The `focus` event equivalent to `willFocus` from before. It fires as soon as the screen is focused, before the animation finishes. I'm not sure what you mean by it fires too late.

Also, for data fetching, there is a special hook: `useFocusEffect`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Comment: What I mean by too late is that the user can see the transition between the old and the new list being loaded, and that's why I wanted to fetch data before navigating to my screen or use placeholders. The perfect idea would be to load the data when the user is not on the screen yet because I would like to avoid showing placeholders each time the user focuses the screen.

Comment: Well because fetching data takes time. There's no event that can tell you that a navigation will happen in future so that you can fetch data earlier. Only you know before you'll do a navigation, so you can fetch data, put it in your global store, and then navigate in the place where you call navigate.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
  /**
   * Your redux action should set loading-state to false after
   * fetch-operation is done...
   */
  reduxActionDoingFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (reduxActionDoingFetch_Loading === false) {
      Navigation.navigate('YourTargetScreen');
    }
  }, [reduxActionDoingFetch_Loading]);
```

Comment: It could work but my data is stored inside the screen component , do I have to use a store then ?

Comment: I believe so ... I've demonstrated the idea using **redux** for example...

Answer (score 0):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently using but the event is fired too late. I would like to fetch my data before the screen comes to focus. (Each time the user navigate to my screen)